# Python 2.7 ERROR: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, str-replace

I have a dictionary like this...

```
 mydict = {"rows": [["col1", "col2", "col3"], ["testing data 1", "testing data 2lk\nIdrjy9dyj", "testing data 3"], ["testing data 2", "testing data 3", "testing data 4"], ["testing data 3", "testing data 4", "testing data 5"]], 
           "columns": ["col1", "col2", "col3"]}
```

I am trying to replace the carriage return `\n` with an html `<br>`.
This is the error I am getting:

> ERROR: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'

This is the code I am trying to get working... If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

```
for items in mydict['rows']:
            i += 1
            newitems = items.replace("\n", "<br>")
            mydict['rows'][i] = newitems
```

Comment: Your mydict contains lists, your error mentions tuples. One of them (or the code) must be wrong.

Comment: `list` doesn't have a `replace` method, either.

Comment: Of course, but there is more strangeness here (like what's `i`? wouldn't that give another error?), let's get the question correct first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following code to replace the `'\n'` with `'<br>'` in your strings

```
for index, sublist in enumerate(mydict['rows']):
    mydict['rows'][index] = [s.replace('\n', '<br>') for s in sublist]
```

Result

```
>>> mydict
{'columns': ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
 'rows': [['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], ['testing data 1', 'testing data 2lk<br>Idrjy9dyj', 'testing data 3'], ['testing data 2', 'testing data 3', 'testing data 4'], ['testing data 3', 'testing data 4', 'testing data 5']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `replace` is a method on a string and you want to call it on each string, but right now you're calling it on the collection itself. You really want to call replace on every individual string in `items`, which you can do with a [list comprehension](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php)

```
for items in mydict['rows']:
            mydict['rows'][i] = [item.replace("\n","<br>") for item in items]
            i += 1
```

You could also do this with another for-loop instead of a list comprehension, but comprehensions are cool and worth knowing about.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the replacement with a nested list comprehension.

```
mydict["rows"] = [[item.replace("\n", "<br>") for item in row] 
                   for row in mydict["rows"]]

>>> mydict["rows"]
[['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
 ['testing data 1', 'testing data 2lk<br>Idrjy9dyj', 'testing data 3'],
 ['testing data 2', 'testing data 3', 'testing data 4'],
 ['testing data 3', 'testing data 4', 'testing data 5']]
```

Answer (score -2):

Say `items` is a tuple.

Try:

```
print(type(items))
```

Because the error I get with the script is:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

And try to print `items`.